# Remove temporary files after compiling with Makefile

Tags: c, makefile, temporary

I'm currently using the following Makefile to compile my C project.

```
RM = rm -f
CFLAGS += -Wextra -Wall -Werror
CFLAGS +=   -I.

NAME = a.out

SRCS =  main.c

OBJS =  $(SRCS:.c=.o)


all:    $(NAME)
        $(NAME): $(OBJS)
        gcc $(OBJS) -o $(NAME) $(LDFLAGS)

clean:
        $(RM) $(OBJS)

fclean: clean
        $(RM) $(NAME)

re: fclean all
```

I would like to add something into my clean command which could remove temporary files, that's to say the files ending with `~`.
I have to do this without use `*~`.

Comment: Why not using `*~`?

Comment: The `makefile` doesn't create any temporary files ending in `~`, where are they coming from?

Comment: gcc seem yes, i got them on each `make` and i can't use *~ due of my school norm prohibits it

Comment: [emacs](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoSave)

Comment: @Stargateur Auto-save files are named #filename#. These are Emacs version files.

Comment: @Barnar my bad wrong doc. [BackupFiles](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Backup-Names.html#Backup-Names)

Comment: cba from where they're coming, I just wanna remove them, thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
TMP =  $(SRCS:.c=.c~)

clean:
        $(RM) -f $(OBJS)
        $(RM) -f $(TMP)
```

or like @Barmar said

```
clean:
    -$(RM) $(OBJS)
    -$(RM) $(TMP)
```

it's better to avoid option in `RM = rm -f` ==> `RM = rm`

[doc](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html)

Comment: Should probably use `-$(RM)` so it doesn't stop the makefile is there are no temporary files.